# Want to return all businesses within a distance of address using PostGIS. Keeps ignoring the distance and returning all companies

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to return all companies within a certain distance of an address, but I can't figure out why I'm getting all the companies in my database as my response.

The desired outcome would be to provide the address id, specify a distance, and return all the companies within that distance.

I've outlined below some of the commands I ran to create the coordinates columns on my tables and some of the queries I've tried running that return all companies.

**NOTE**:
The coordinates columns are: `SRID=4326;POINT(-LONG LAT)` but putting them in the table gave me some weird code formatting error, and StackOverflow wasn't letting me post it.

---

Ran these SQL commands

```
ADD COLUMN "coordinates" geometry(POINT, 4326)
CREATE INDEX "address_coordinates_idx" ON "addresses" USING GIST ("coordinates");
```

```
ADD COLUMN "coordinates" geometry(POINT, 4326)
CREATE INDEX "companies_coordinates_idx" ON "companies" USING GIST ("coordinates");
```

Addresses Table

| id | address | city | state | coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | fake name | city | state | refer to note |
| uuid | fake name | city | state | refer to note |
| uuid | fake name | city | state | refer to note |

Companies Table

| id | name | phone | description | coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | fake name | fake phone | fake desc | refer to note |
| uuid | fake name | fake phone | fake desc | refer to note |
| uuid | fake name | fake phone | fake desc | refer to note |

Current SQL Query:

```
SELECT companies.*
FROM companies
WHERE ST_DWithin(companies.coordinates,
                   (SELECT coordinates
                    FROM addresses
                    WHERE id = 'the address id' ), 80467.2);
```

Another query that gave me the same results

```
SELECT companies.*
FROM companies, addresses
WHERE ST_DWithin(companies.coordinates, addresses.coordinates, 80467.2)
AND addresses.id = 'the address id';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`st_dwithin()` over **geometries** uses the CRS unit, so for 4326 it's in degrees, and 80467 degrees is the whole world. When used with **geographies**, it's in meters.

You would also have to index the geographies.

While there, the same query would be more efficient with a join on `st_dwithin`

```
CREATE INDEX "address_coordinates_geog_idx" ON "addresses" USING GIST (("coordinates"::geography));
CREATE INDEX "companies_coordinates_geog_idx" ON "companies" USING GIST (("coordinates"::geography));

SELECT companies.*
FROM addresses 
JOIN companies
  ON ST_DWithin(companies.coordinates::geography, addresses.coordinates::geography, 80467.2)
WHERE addresses.id = 'the address id';
```